# Latest file from ftp server using wget or some other way

Tags: wget, ftp

How can I download the latest file available in ftp server using wget.
 If I am using the below command it is giving all the files.

wget ftp://id:password@ftpserver/dir/*

Regards,
Ram.

Comment: why don't you give us a little bit less information to work with?

Answer (score 8):

Just add the "-N" option to wget to ignore files older than what you have locally. You could also add the "-nc" to completely skip a file if it already exists, even if the one on FTP is newer.

wget -N ftp://id:password@ftpserver/dir/*

Answer (score 6):

The answer is that you probably can't do this using just wget or any other single tool that I am aware of.

What you probably need to do is write a script that will use wget/curl/whatever that will request a directory listing from the ftp server.  Then the script will select and retrieve the right file based on the file's name, or some other criteria.

Comment: using wget I am able to get all files issue is if I have that file already then it is coming and storeing as file_name.1
I want to download the files which are not available there.

Answer (score 3):

My Solution is this:

```
curl 'ftp://server.de/dir/'$(curl 'ftp://server.de/dir/' 2>/dev/null | tail -1 | awk '{print $(NF)}')
```

Comment: I needed also the latest items*.csv file however curl will not allow wildcart patterns so I solved with a grep command piped after curl. Thanks for sharing your solution as I like it!

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the file you want to download. Using '*' will download every file in the directory 'dir'.

Example:

```
wget ftp://gnjilux.cc.fer.hr/welcome.msg
```

...will download exactly the file 'welcome.msg' from the mentioned server.

Check the [Wget-Manual](http://www.editcorp.com/Personal/Lars_Appel/wget/v1/wget_7.html).

**Update**: I'm not sure if I get your problem. Are you trying to sync the content of the remote server (machine running the FTP daemon) with your local server? Are you looking for something like [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) functionality over FTP? If yes, you could try [ftpsync](http://ossw.ibcl.at/FTPSync/) (wget alone won't help in this case).

Comment: Hi The file is like file-name_YYYYMMDD.sql.gz
where YYYY - year, MM - month, DD -date
I cant specify the exact file name

Comment: Seems like a database backup / schema script

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my non-ideal but simple solution will be useful for somebody.

First, I've installed **proftpd**. Here is /ftp directory tree example:

```
/ftp/
/ftp/file1
/ftp/file1/subfile1
/ftp/file1/subfile2
/ftp/file2
```

Then I added task in **crontab** to execute every minute this script:

```
PACKAGES=$(find /ftp/* -type d -not -name 'lost+found')
for PACKAGE in "${PACKAGES[@]}"; do
  echo $(ls -I 'latest' -Atp "${PACKAGE}" | grep -v '/' | head -n 1) > "${PACKAGE}"/latest
done
```

So for every file (or package in my case) you need to create individual directory and there will be file 'latest' that contains name of latest file in that directory. If you want to get latest version of some file then you can just execute command:

```
wget ftp://"${FTP_SRV}"/"${FILE}"/$(curl -s ftp://"${FTP_SRV}"/"${FILE}"/latest)
```

Comment: You should add some quotes to that script — and, ideally, not loop over find’s output in the first place.

Comment: @Scott, I've understood your remark about quotes, but I don't get you about loop over find's output. Could you clarify this?

Comment: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/23408)